# Can we defined nested id as `@+id/index/btn1` in android?

Tags: android

We can define ids like this:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/btn1" />
```

But there are many activities and many components, the ids may be duplicated with others easily.

Is it able to define nested ides, like:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/index/btn1" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot. However, you can either 1) create the semblance of a namespace using _ for example:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/index_btn1" />
```

or 2) you can reuse the same Id but in a different xml file. As long as there aren't duplicate ids inside of a view, findViewById() will work fine.

See the section on IDs in the docs for more info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html